# Cache API for requested ID for specific time / Django admin filter

Tags: python-3.x, django, redis, django-admin

I'm learning python for few weeks and I'm creating hockey app. I have two problems.

1. [text](https://gitlab.com/dword4/nhlapi/-/blob/master/stats-api.md)

In this API we have about 1000 players with specific ID. I know how I get specific value and how I create for loop for all values, but I don't want send request for all players (ofc) and store this values in a database or send request every time when some app user want it.
So when user send request for example for Ovechkin, for McDavid..., how I could cache this for some time because data should be updated - if they play another match? Should I do something in Redis or django-cache?

2. I created models in Django - Team, League, Fixture. I added teams and assign them League(NHL, SHL, DEL etc.) and for fixture? I chose league NHL and saw all teams(included from Germany, Sweden) still. How I can create live filter in Django Admin when I click on NHL = all non-NHL teams disappear.

```
class League(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    league = models.ForeignKey(to=League, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Fixture(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey(League, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='fixtures')
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='home_games')
    away_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='away_games')
    home_goals = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    away_goals = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.home_team} vs {self.away_team}"
```